# GET https://www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js net::ERR_BLOCKED_BY_CLIENT

Tags: javascript, html, wordpress, google-analytics

Установил гугл аналитик, вставил код перед закрывающимся тегом , в аналитике сделал "цель", но в отчетах нет ни каких действий по сайту, открыл "просмотреть код страницы" и обнаружил вот такую ошибку net::ERR_BLOCKED_BY_CLIENT, адблок выключен, как мне это исправить, благодарен любой помощи

Comment: Значит, что-то еще включено. Blocked by client - блокирован браузером клиента. Там и надо искать.

Comment: chrome переустановить если, может помочь ?

Comment: Отключить все расширения

Answer (score 1):

Я создал ещё один профиль в Хроме, куда добавил только плагины отладки аналитик.
В нём и тестирую всё, проблемы сейчас не наблюдаю, хотя установлен декстопный адгвард, который на время тестов не выключаю.

А в рабочих профилях, ошибка валится постоянно даже если выключена блокировка на странице. Раньше у меня такое было, когда антивирус тоже блокировал рекламу.